# Would anyone be able to help a fellow Tester out? [Twitter Reqd]

Tags: manual-testing

Obviously this isnt a question as such, just a hopeful request for assistance.

I wonder if you might consider helping a fellow QA/Tester out and asking your follows to vote for me (Rob Arnell) on twitter in a Salesforce poll. I am Salesforce QA Lead and am hoping the testing community may help a fellow QA out against two others in a competition to attend Dreamforce - a Salesforce event in San Francisco later this year. This would really enable me to enhance my knowledge and help me apply further testing practices to Salesforce in my role.

The Twitter post is below if you are able to share the link on your twitter feed.

https://twitter.com/salesforce/status/1006479052096581632

I understand if you are unable to but thought I would ask and obviously appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: This really isn't the place for this type of request. Good luck with your attempt, though.

Comment: How do you vote to close a post, or is that tied to your reputation score?

Comment: i really wanted to leave open but was worried about the precedent it might set.  i don't usually worry about precedents but in this case i do

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is dig in here on the 'Software Quality Assurance & Testing' Stack Exchange. By asking technical questions and sharing your testing knowledge in answers you will probably better your career more than attending a conference. From your LinkedIn profile you have some deep experiences and there are plenty of good questions needing answers.

Good luck in furthering your career in Saleforce testing.